# Como hacer multiples registros a la DB mediante a API rest de Django, JSON

Tags: json, django

Buen día, tengo este proyecto:

Es una pequeña APIrest para registro de compañías mediante JSON,
los campos son: nombre de la compañía, Pagina WEB y año de Fundación.

mis archivos de Django son los siguientes:

view.py

```
class CompanyView(View):

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, id=0):
        if (id > 0):
            companies = list(Company.objects.filter(id=id).values())
            if len(companies) > 0:
                company = companies[0]
                datos = {'message': "Success", 'company': company}
            else:
                datos = {'message': "Company not found..."}
            return JsonResponse(datos)
        else:
            companies = list(Company.objects.values())
            if len(companies) > 0:
                datos = {'message': "Success", 'companies': companies}
            else:
                datos = {'message': "Companies not found..."}
            return JsonResponse(datos)

    def post(self, request):
        # print(request.body)
        jd = json.loads(request.body)
        # print(jd)
        Company.objects.create(name=jd['name'], website=jd['website'], foundation=jd['foundation'])
        datos = {'message': "Success"}
        return JsonResponse(datos)

    def put(self, request, id):
        jd = json.loads(request.body)
        companies = list(Company.objects.filter(id=id).values())
        if len(companies) > 0:
            company = Company.objects.get(id=id)
            company.name = jd['name']
            company.website = jd['website']
            company.foundation = jd['foundation']
            company.save()
            datos = {'message': "Success"}
        else:
            datos = {'message': "Company not found..."}
        return JsonResponse(datos)

    def delete(self, request, id):
        companies = list(Company.objects.filter(id=id).values())
        if len(companies) > 0:
            Company.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
            datos = {'message': "Success"}
        else:
            datos = {'message': "Company not found..."}
        return JsonResponse(datos)
```

urls.py

```
path('companies/', CompanyView.as_view(), name='companies_list'),
path('companies/<int:id>', CompanyView.as_view(), name='companies_process')
```

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    foundation = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Me funciona Correctamente solo si hago un POST por registro, es decir un JSON con un registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si hago POST con un JSON con varios registros me da error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago el registro múltiple, es decir un JSON con decenas de compañías?

De antemano Muchas gracias!

Comment: hola,  solo puedes recibir 1 registro a la vez, por eso cuando mandas mas de uno te da error, que tal si  guardas los registros ingresados en un diccionario y luego muestras el contenido, saludos

Comment: Tienes razón, es algo muy sencillo, gracias!